# Install4j exception during all installations

Tags: install4j

When trying to install any Install4j installer (tried with several different of our installers that are normally working correctly), I get the following Setup error on my Windows 10 laptop:

> The installation/removal of a previoius program was not completed. You will need to restart your computer to complete that installation.
>
> After restarting your computer, run Setup again to complete the installation of Program name.

Restarting my computer does not help. Removing the "PendingFileRenameOperations" from the registry did not help either, even after restarting (from https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/310335/error-message-the-installation-removal-of-a-previous-program-was-not-completed ). The install4j logs do not mention this problem, so no help from that either.

This issue started after doing some program uninstallations (both install4j and not install4j) and some got stuck and needed to be stopped with Task Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the registry keys

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\install4j\RebootCheckFile
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\install4j\RebootCheckFile
```

and remove them if they exist.